# How to upload file in Selenium with Flash uploader

Tags: flash, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to upload photos in Selenium. The uploader is in Flash, however it doesn't work. When I use the normal file uploader (by file input), it works. Can anyone help?

Comment: I think, Selenium cannot handle Flash components. You should see this: https://code.google.com/p/flash-selenium/